# RequireJS isn't working for me

Tags: jquery, requirejs, cdn, velocity.js

I'm working on a personal project and I'm using a lot of JavaScript code and working with a few libraries and plugins like jQuery and Velocity.js. I don't know why I can't make it working, I've followed the RequireJS documentation and a lot of tutorials, but I'm always getting errors in the console.

This is how my website's depository is like:

```
Main folder
  |
  |index.html
  |
  |
  |——JS folder ——
         |
         |require.js
         |config.js
         |main.js
         |
         |————————
```

In index.html I'm calling the RequireJS in this way

```
<script data-main="js/config" src="js/require.js"></script>
```

And in the config I have the paths for each CDN depositories, like this:

```
requirejs.config({
"baseUrl": "js",
"paths": {
  "jquery": "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js",
  "velocity": "//cdn.jsdelivr.net/velocity/1.2.2/velocity.min.js",
  "velocity-ui": "//cdn.jsdelivr.net/velocity/1.2.2/velocity.ui.min.js",
  "bootstrap": "//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js",
  "main": "main"
}
});
```

In the same file (config.js), after closing the requirejs.config I'm calling my main.js file in this way:

```
require(['main']);
```

And inside the main.js I'm using jquery, velocity and velocity-ui.

```
require([ "jquery", "velocity", "velocity-ui" ], function ($, Velocity) {
 //my code here
 });
```

After that, I'm always getting errors in console, like

```
Error: Script error for: jquery
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
---
Error: Script error for: velocity
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
---
Error: Script error for: velocity-ui
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong ...

Comment: Have you tried to give url:s for required libs with http: involved to the path. Especially when running from file the // traducts to file:// which obviously is not what you want to.

Comment: I've also tried and doesn't work neither

Comment: What happens if you had the .js extension to "main" in your config?

Comment: It give me an error, because it would search for a file named "main.js.js"

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the `.js` extension in your path. Requirejs Doc says

> The path that is used for a module name should not include an extension, since the path mapping could be for a directory. The path mapping code will automatically add the .js extension when mapping the module name to a path.

So change code in config.js to the following:

```js
requirejs.config({
    "baseUrl": "js",
    "paths": {
        "jquery": "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min",
        "velocity": "//cdn.jsdelivr.net/velocity/1.2.2/velocity.min",
        "velocity-ui": "//cdn.jsdelivr.net/velocity/1.2.2/velocity.ui.min",
        "bootstrap": "//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min",
        "main": "main"
    }
});

require(['main']);
```

Comment: It's giving me same errors after remove the ".js" extension

Comment: @Jotakun That's strange, I use exactly same file structure and same code as you. I put `console.log($)` and  `console.log(Velocity);` in `main.js`, they are shown the correct values.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using require.js correct. You should have only one `require()` call and give it a callback. All the rest of your project's files should be wrapped with `define()`.

Example:

`main.js` should look like:

```
define([ "jquery", "velocity", "velocity-ui" ], function ($, Velocity) {
    //my code here
    // return something
});
```

and in `config.js` you should have something like:

```
require(['main'], function (main) {
    // do something with main module... like init stuff...
});
```

Comment: But, how should I call all files? that's what I don't understand. I'm using define() at the beginning of each file and specifying which library/module I'm using in the file. Like this:
      `define([ "jquery", "velocity", "velocity-ui" ], function ($, Velocity) {
          //my code
       });`
but I don't know where or how can I call this file. I'm calling it from the html, like this:
       `<script>
        require(['config'], function(){
            require(['main']);
        });
    </script>`

Maybe this is what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Added examples to clarify better